# Access div id from jstl core tag?

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, jstl

I have an div tag with style as none and id as ack.With in if core tag i need to access div id and need to display message.

```
<body>
<div class="alert alert-success" id="ack"
                    style="display: none" align="center">
                </div>

<c:if test="${LegacyDataForm.petDetails ne null}">
//how to access div id from here
</c:if>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like below :

```
<body>
<div class="alert alert-success" id="ack" style="display: none" align="center">
</div>

<c:if test="${LegacyDataForm.petDetails ne null}">
<script>
//how to access div id from here
var myDiv = document.getElementById("ack");
myDiv.style.display = "block";
myDiv.innerHTML = "My message!";
</script> 
</c:if>
</body>
```

You can use jquery if you already used it.